# Android emulator screen size is not same as preview screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

As you can see in below image, I wrote a sting of numbers and their appearance on emulator screen and Preview of Studio is different. On emulator screen on left, I have marked the space with red color, but if you see on the Preview window on the right, there exists no space. How do I make the Preview screen size as same as my emulator screen?

For the emulator, I have set screen size as 5.5 inch and resolution 720x1280. The text size I have set to `66sp` in `xml` file.

[image]

Comment: Got. It was the `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias`. If its not set to 0 then those gap appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the preview screen size you can select another reference device in the drop down where you currently have the Nexus 4 selected, and change it to the same size as the emulator:
[image]